# CMD won't execute basic CD \

Tags: cmd, cd

I cannot get CMD or powershell to access anything beyond the first sub directory on a drive without typing the full path.  Keeps telling me the system cannot find the specified path.

i.e. This works:

**d: cd \dev jobs**

and this works:

**d: cd \dev jobs\sites**

but this doesn't work

**d:\dev jobs> cd \sites**

I'm running latest windows 10. 
c: is my system drive
replicated this proess in the c drive directory and met with the same results

(Please, I'm not asking how to change directories but rather understand why the command line seems to be misbehaving)

Any ideas or suggestions on where to start?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Change to d:\dev jobs > cd sites

Comment: nope, comes back with "system cannot find the path" . Any ideas why this might be occurring or how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the unuseful comment vote? That's the right answer.

If you are in `d:\dev jobs` and you `cd sites`, it will work. From `d:\dev jobs`, `cd \sites` does not work because it is looking for sites in the root folder (ie. `d:\sites`).

You want to use a relative path there.

Comment: Didn't mean to imply that you were incorrect. If my CMD were functioning correctly that would indeed be the right answer. Note in my question though - my issue is that correct commands are not generating expected results.

If I attempt d:/dev jobs> cd sites  it still gives me the error

Comment: Also I just noticed that I omitted the > in my question.  I meant to say d:\dev jobs> cd/sites

Comment: You don't put the caret. From d:\dev jobs, you just put cd sites (no slash).

Comment: The slash before sites indicates that you want to go to d:\sites, you want a relative path, so just cd sites will do the trick.

Comment: I think there's a little miscommunication on my end, but I'm trying exactly as you suggested (or at least I think I am).  So Here's an exact line by line of my cmd:

C:\Users\Jamie>d:

D:\>cd \dev jobs

D:\dev jobs>cd sites
The system cannot find the path specified.

D:\dev jobs>

Comment: wow. ok I'm an idiot.  somebody changed the folder structure. sorry for wasting your time, but thanks for your help